# Ошибка ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, anaconda, keras

Пишу нейронку для определения рукописных цифр

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

json_file = open("mnist_model.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("mnist_model.h5")

loaded_model.compile(loss= "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

img_path ="7.png"
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28,28), grayscale=True)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show

x =image.img_to_array(img)
x = 255 - x 
x/= 255
np.expland_dims(x, axis=0)
predicction = loaded_model.predict(x)
prediction = np_utils.categorical_pobabs_to_classes(prediction)
print(prediction)
```

Все сделал обучил ее решил применить, но тут вылезли проблемки:

1. При запуске выводит график и вот такую ошибку

   > AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'expland_dims'
2. при вводе `%matpliotlib inline` подсвечивает его как синтаксическую ошибку
3. вот в этой строчке `img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28,28), grayscale=True)` вылезает `ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)`

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: `%matpliotlib inline` работает в jupyter notebook, но не будет работать внутри скрипта, поэтому IDE в котором вы пишете и подчеркивает как синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: По первой ошибке скорее вам нужно не exp**l**and_dims, а [expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: @insolor Ладно с этим разобрался но тут тадаам 'ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)'

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, с указанием на какой строке эта ошибка. Судя по ошибке, вы подаете на вход какой-то функции 3-мерный массив, а нужно 2-мерный.

Comment: Еще, обратите внимание, у вас в одном месте `predicction`, а ниже - `prediction`.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, вопрос изменил)